# How to poll directory for a file?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I need to be able to poll a directory for a specific file using SCP, and once the file has been processed, it needs to keep polling.

Is this possible with Spring Batch?

Comment: Can use other framework like Apache Camel? http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: does spring-integration have something useful for this kind of problem?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I think it does, I was looking around and found this,http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#files But I'm kinda having trouble getting a grasp on where to start, never used spring-integration.

Comment: @hutingung I need to stay with Spring, at most just create a java thread and launch the job when it finds the file.

Comment: I have never used too,sorry. but try adding spring-integration tag and wait

Comment: If you want long term solution, I would strongly suggest you to look into Enterprise Integration Pattern (http://www.eaipatterns.com/) @LucaBassoRicci is right. Spring Integration is is another framework that implement EIP. I will choose those framework to avoid boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to handle this is using Spring Integration.  The way I'd address it is with a Spring Integration flow that uses a SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter to retrieve the files, then passes the transferred name to Spring Batch to launch.  The flow would actually be similar to the sample in the SpringBatchIntegration in my Spring Batch Webinar here: https://github.com/mminella/SpringBatchWebinar

In that example, I use Twitter to launch the job.  The only thing you'd need to change is the twitter piece for the SFTP.

Comment: So, the batch job is not started until the file is found, is it?

Comment: Correct.  The Batch job is launched once the file is downloaded.

Comment: Where do you specify which batch job to launch once the file is downloaded?

Comment: In your case, you could probably hard code or inject it in the transformer that creates the `JobLaunchRequest`.

Comment: Thanks, here is a great example which I found which does exactly what I wanted to do, https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample/tree/master/payment-import. Instead of using integration-file, I'm using integration-sftp.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve the same question (but just accessing to the local filesystem) and I did not find any solution in the framework, so I ended up creating my own class which polls for the file and creates a resource.I know this is just a workaround, but I haven't found a better way to do that so far.

I can't remember where (maybe in the "retry handling" part) but I read in the documentation something like *"batch jobs should not try to solve issues like files not found, connections down and so, these kind of errors should make the job raise an error to be handled by operators"* so I gave up...

On the other hand Spring Retry was part of Spring batch and now is a new separate library, maybe you just can assume the file is there and if the reader does not find it, let the step fail and  establish a "retry policy" for that step, but for me that's overkill.

This is what I did:

```
<bean id="resourceFactory"
      class="com.mycompany.batch.zip.ResourceFactory">
    <property name="retryAttemps" value="${attemps}" />
    <property name="timeBetweenAttemps" value="${timeBetweenAttemps}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myResource"
      factory-bean="resourceFactory" factory-method="create" scope="step">
    <constructor-arg value="${absolutepath}" type="java.lang.String"  />
</bean>

<!--step scope to avoid looking for the file when deployment-->
<bean id="myReader"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="retailer" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    <property name="resource" ref="myResource" />
</bean>
```

And this is my class:

```
public class ResourceFactory {

    public static final Logger LOG= LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceFactory.class);
    private int retryAttemps;
    private long timeBetweenAttemps;

    public Resource create(String resource) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Resource r;
        File f=new File(resource);
        int attemps=1;
        while (!f.exists()) {
            if (attemps<this.retryAttemps) {
                attemps++;
                LOG.warn("File "+resource+" not found, waiting "+timeBetweenAttemps+
                           " before retrying. Attemp: "+attemps+" of "+this.retryAttemps);
                Thread.sleep(this.timeBetweenAttemps);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(resource);
            }
            if (resource!=null && resource.endsWith(".zip")) {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(resource);
                ZipEntry entry=zipFile.entries().nextElement();
                if (entry==null) {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("The zip file has no entries inside");
                }

                //TODO Test if a buffered Stream is faster than the raw InputStream
                InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));

                r= new InputStreamResource(is);
                if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    int size=(int)entry.getSize();
                    LOG.info("Opening a compressed file of "+size+" bytes");
                }
            } else {
                LOG.info("Opening a regular file");
                r= new FileSystemResource(f);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows a better way to do that, I'll gladly remove this answer (and implement the new solution)

PS: BTW, I've found some faults in my code when reviewing this post, so for me this is being helpful even with no other answers :)

Comment: Does this take up a lot of computing resources? I would assume that having it run in a loop till it finds something will make it use up the CPU a lot.

Comment: No, there is a `Trhead.sleep(...`). The way I use it is polling every 60000 millisecs (one minute) ten times,